# What is the densest material on earth?

Tags: physical-chemistry, metals, elements

Apart from the elements, do we know of *materials* that are denser (and not including exotic and theoretical matter)? I.e. can an alloy be denser than the sum of its compounds, for example if the new lattice packs denser than each of the compounds it's made from? My curiosity was spurred from rumors of a material called ultradense deuterium (not confirmed to exist), that apparently packs something like 140kg/cm^3.

Comment: Are you asking about any material, or just metallic ones? Does it literally have to exist on earth (at standard temperature and pressure?), or is degenerate neutron matter an acceptable answer?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36064/17609

Comment: “If you had a cubic centimeter of this stuff, it would weigh 40 billion tons.” http://www.zmescience.com/science/physics/quark-gluon-plasma-lhc-26052011/

Comment: It always amuses me that people use lead as an exemplar for density when it is only middling dense compared to gold, mercury, and tungsten much less exotics like uranium metal, osmium, and heavymet.

Comment: Inside a nuclear explosion the pit material gets compressed by a factor of two or three, or so, if I remember correctly. That's still very far away from nuclear densities, which, of course, can be found everywhere.

Comment: @dmckee That's my bad - changed it to something more appropriate.

Comment: Somebody changed the wording of my question completely and added Lead. Not sure why. I'm not talking about neutron stars and I'm not talking about metals only. Any stone, carbon, semiconductor, plastic, organic slime or whatever we can hold in our hand here on Earth. And the reason I ask was because it could be that some atoms would pack together more densely than just the element alone, at least theoretically.

Comment: Then it belongs to chemistry.

Comment: Related:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60022/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60022/59023)

Comment: To those that put this question on hold, how can asking for THE densest material on earth be "too broad"?

Comment: It is worth noting that iridium becomes denser than osmium above 2.98 GPa, https://www.technology.matthey.com/article/58/3/137-141/ Binary sphere packings can also be noticeably denser than single packings: all in all, this is a relevant question I think should be reopened.

Comment: @Pedery Because the word "material" is incredibly broad. It includes arbitrarily obscure compounds, alloys, mixtures, solutions, emulsions, colloids, suspensions, etc. and knowing the answer requires knowing the density of arbitrarily complex configurations of matter of all types. Also, because the answer is almost certainly not ambiguous; the same material under different conditions can have radically different density (for example, compare water at -40 degrees to water at 300 degrees Celsius). Some complex materials might not even _exist_ in most conditions!

Comment: I'm aware that it's a broad term and that's on purpose. However, "densest material on Earth" is frankly speaking much less so. I think I clarify this in the question description below where I underscore that I'm not asking about exotic matter and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Densest material on Earth is probably [Osmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium) at 22.59 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. What the densest material at the Earth's core may be I do not know - probably still Osmium unless some other element forms a higher density [allotrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy) under the pressure.

Comment: The density of osmium (22.59 g/cm^3) is only very slightly higher than the density of iridium (22.56 g/cm^3) by 0.13%, but the bulk modulus of osmium (B=462 GPa) is significantly higher than that of iridium (B=320 GPa). So iridium is more compressible than osmium, and so the density of iridium will quickly overtake that of osmium if both are subjected to moderate high pressures (a few kbars).

Comment: You answer on the densest _material_, as was the specific question. But Osmium is the densest (naturally occurring) _element_ (see your first link). So, explaining that step would help (me). Perhaps exclude stuff like Osmiridium and Iridosmine?

Comment: Alloying with less dense materials usually lowers the density of the final alloy. I do not know of any exceptions, although there may be some

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I emphasized *material* since any stuff you can pick up and hold in your hand will do. Is it given that an element is the densest material on the planet?